# How to start an android app with valgrind

Tags: android, android-ndk, valgrind, gdbserver

I've been searching for the last week trying to find an answer to this question.

How do I start an Android app with valgrind? I know I can start an app with the 'am' command, but it starts the app and exits.

I'm writing an app that uses the NDK for native C code, and I need to check it for suspected memory errors.

Edit:

I've learned a little more. You can "wrap" an app with a shell script.

Here's the shell script I'm using:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
VGPARAMS='--error-limit=no'
export TMPDIR=/data/data/com.starlon.froyvisuals
exec /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind $VGPARAMS $*
```

And here's setprop:

```
adb shell setprop wrap.com.starlon.froyvisuals "logwrapper valgrind"
```

And here's how I start the app:

```
adb shell am start -n com.starlon.froyvisuals/.FroyVisuals
```

I don't think this is right, because I'm not sure where the shell script fits in and I'm not seeing anything in logcat. Any hints?

Edit2: 
Oh the shell script is indicated with "setprop" command above. So

```
adb shell setprop wrap.com.starlon.froyvisuals "logwrapper /data/local/val.sh"
```

I'm still not seeing anything in logcat.

Comment: For how to run your app through Valgrind see my script from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19235439/313113

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to clear the logcat first

```
prompt# adb logcat -c
prompt# adb logcat
```

You should be able to see the logs coming in once you triggered your application.

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.hellojni/.HelloJni
```

I had problems with my shell script and i used this instead.

```
adb shell setprop wrap.com.example.hellojni "logwrapper /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind"
```

You should be able to pass in the parameter right after valgrind

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem too. In my situation, I edit the "val.sh" in windows & adb push it to the emulator, but the shell script could not be executed correctly. Then I use a echo "***" > val.sh style to make the "val.sh" and It works well.

So you should first make sure the "val.sh" could be interpreted correctly.