# start android app with valgrind

Tags: android, valgrind

I am trying to start an android app from valgrind on Android Phone from adb.
I have already installed valgrind on android phone.

What are the steps that i need to follow to start an android app from valgrind on Android Phone from adb.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For **how to run your app through Valgrind on Android (ARM)** see my script from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19235439/313113

Answer (score -2):

Check this : [How to start an android app with valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123124/how-to-start-an-android-app-with-valgrind)

It worked for me on a Android 4.0 device. 
This requires you use adb shell to type in some commands.