# Is there any step-by-step documentation to use Valgrind?

Tags: android, android-ndk, valgrind

I want to use Valgrind to check memory leaks for my game written in C++ for Android platform. I saw this link:http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.readme-android.html but this documentation is not very well written and explained for beginners. Therefore, I am looking for step-by-step documentation for Valgrind.

Comment: The docs in that link appear to be for a stand-alone app.  If you want it to work with an Android app, it's more like: (1) build valgrind for Android from source for the target device; (2) install it; (3) install the symbolized versions of all "interesting" libraries; (4) set a system property that causes system_server to launch your app under valgrind instead of just forking it out of zygote.  Generally requires a full Android source tree (which includes valgrind in `external/valgrind`) and a rooted device.

Comment: For getting started see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19255366/313113