# Memory leak in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Which is better tool (adb shell procmem  or adb shell showmap ) to check memory leak in native heap? And why?

I have used both but procmem is showing memory leak but showmap does not.

Comment: I've heard [`valgrind`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123124/how-to-start-an-android-app-with-valgrind) is what you use when tracking native leaks

Comment: If any 1 has idea about the diff in procmem and showmap?And why they are showing different results?