# Valgrind on android 5/L crashes

Tags: android, linux, crash, valgrind

I have cross-compiled Valgrind for android target eabi x86 with NDK R10b.
When launching my app per steps as for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123124/how-to-start-an-android-app-with-valgrind) valgrind crashes.
Log

```js
10-29 11:16:07.468: D/AndroidRuntime(2240): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-29 11:16:07.469: D/AndroidRuntime(2240): CheckJNI is ON
10-29 11:16:07.486: E/memtrack(2240): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-29 11:16:07.486: E/android.os.Debug(2240): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-29 11:16:07.500: D/AndroidRuntime(2240): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
10-29 11:16:07.502: I/ActivityManager(1236): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=...} from uid 0 on display 0
10-29 11:16:07.518: D/AndroidRuntime(2240): Shutting down VM
10-29 11:16:07.519: I/art(2240): Debugger is no longer active
10-29 11:16:07.522: E/libprocessgroup(2250): failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10053: Read-only file system
10-29 11:16:07.522: W/Zygote(2250): createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
10-29 11:16:07.523: I/art(2250): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-29 11:16:07.524: E/art(2240): Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
10-29 11:16:07.524: I/AndroidRuntime(2240): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_1' failed
10-29 11:16:09.746: D/AndroidRuntime(2264): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-29 11:16:09.848: D/AndroidRuntime(2264): CheckJNI is ON
10-29 11:16:10.278: I/art(2264): Counter: 1
10-29 11:16:10.318: I/start-valgrind.sh(2263): No [stack] line found in /proc/self/maps!
10-29 11:16:10.321: A/libc(2264): No [stack] line found in /proc/self/maps!
10-29 11:16:10.341: A/libc(2264): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2264 (...)
10-29 11:16:10.580: I/DEBUG(948): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-29 11:16:10.580: I/DEBUG(948): Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/sdk_phone_x86/generic_x86:5.0/LRX09D/1504858:eng/test-keys'
10-29 11:16:10.580: I/DEBUG(948): Revision: '0'
10-29 11:16:10.580: I/DEBUG(948): ABI: 'x86'
10-29 11:16:10.580: I/DEBUG(948): pid: 2264, tid: 2264, name: ...  >>> /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind <<<
10-29 11:16:10.580: I/DEBUG(948): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
10-29 11:16:10.581: I/DEBUG(948): Abort message: 'No [stack] line found in /proc/self/maps!'
10-29 11:16:10.581: I/DEBUG(948):     eax 00000000  ebx 000008d8  ecx 00000006  edx 00000000
10-29 11:16:10.581: I/DEBUG(948):     esi 00000000  edi 00000000
10-29 11:16:10.581: I/DEBUG(948):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
10-29 11:16:10.581: I/DEBUG(948):     eip 3806dd52  ebp 00000000  esp 628cfe40  flags 00200202
10-29 11:16:10.581: I/DEBUG(948): backtrace:
10-29 11:16:10.581: I/DEBUG(948):     #00 pc 0006dd52  /data/local/Inst/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux
10-29 11:16:10.583: W/NativeCrashListener(1236): Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 2264
10-29 11:16:10.597: I/DEBUG(948): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_09
10-29 11:16:10.597: I/BootReceiver(1236): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
10-29 11:16:10.637: I/start-valgrind.sh(2263): start-valgrind.sh terminated by exit(1)
10-29 11:16:10.638: I/Zygote(954): Process 2250 exited cleanly (1)
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/Zygote(954): Error reading pid from wrapped process, child may have died
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/Zygote(954): java.io.EOFException
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/Zygote(954):  at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/Zygote(954):  at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:103)
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/Zygote(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleParentProc(ZygoteConnection.java:974)
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/Zygote(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:276)
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/Zygote(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/Zygote(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:690)
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/ActivityManager(1236): Slow operation: 3129ms so far, now at startProcess: returned from zygote!
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/ActivityManager(1236): Slow operation: 3129ms so far, now at startProcess: done updating battery stats
10-29 11:16:10.639: W/ActivityManager(1236): Slow operation: 3129ms so far, now at startProcess: building log message
10-29 11:16:10.639: I/ActivityManager(1236): Start proc ... for activity ...: pid=2250 uid=10053 gids={50053, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015} abi=x86
10-29 11:16:10.640: W/ActivityManager(1236): Slow operation: 3129ms so far, now at startProcess: starting to update pids map
10-29 11:16:10.640: W/ActivityManager(1236): Slow operation: 3130ms so far, now at startProcess: done updating pids map
10-29 11:16:10.640: W/ActivityManager(1236): Slow operation: 3130ms so far, now at startProcess: done starting proc!
10-29 11:16:17.520: W/ActivityManager(1236): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
10-29 11:16:20.650: W/ActivityManager(1236): Process ProcessRecord{1daddf3b 2250:.../u0a53} failed to attach
10-29 11:16:20.650: I/ActivityManager(1236): Killing 2250:.../u0a53 (adj -100): start timeout
```

1. this also happens to me on ARM emulator for Android 5/L
2. I am using ubuntu 14
3. manual valgrind launch such as /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind /data/local/sample-bin works without a problem
4. this was working fine with the same Valgrind compilation on emulator API 18 (ARM)
5. I've tried remounting the file system in write-allowed mode using
   `adb shell mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system`
   and
   `mount -o ro,remount /system`
   and
   `adb root && adb remount`
   -- none does the trick

Has anyone have any ideas what might be the problem here ?

Comment: What about `No [stack] line found in /proc/self/maps!` error? Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error from the emulator's Widget Preview app:

```
E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10052: Read-only file system
```

After various web searches and experiments, I discovered that the emulator's `/sdcard` was indeed set to read-only. (You can test this by trying to touch or push a file in adb shell, or using Android Device Manager to explore the file system.)

The bug and workaround that worked are described in [Issue 78434](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78434).

**Workaround**

- Go to your ADV folder in .android folder and find your AVD's `config.ini` file, e.g. `~/.android/avd/Nexus5_v19.avd/config.ini`.
- Open it with a text editor. If you're on Windows, use a text editor that can handle Unix newlines.
- Change `hw.sdCard=no` to `hw.sdCard=yes`.
- Save that, re-launch the emulator, and test that /sdcard is writeable.

Comment: It has always been set to yes. It did not change anything.

Comment: Sometimes even with `hw.sdCard=yes` the simulated sdcard isn't writable. What happens when you test writing to it, e.g. `adb shell` then `cd /sdcard && touch foo.txt`? Sometimes I also had to use the AVD manager to create a fresh simulated sdcard for the AVD, then check `hw.sdCard=yes` again, and then it was writable. Either way, this might not be the (only) cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've encountered this same problem and the above solution didn't work for me. I figured it out as it occurred exactly after I added Firebase Storage to my app.
Checked the `build.gradle(Module:app)`, found Firebase different versions conflict, changed all of them to the same version, Sync Project and now it works :) Hope this help for future reference.